# What condition on Decision space imply it's a decision tree

Tags: machine-learning, recursive-algorithms, decision-problems, decision-trees

Let's say we have tabular data(numerical) and each column is dimension hence each row is a data point in $R^n$ if there are $n$ columns. The decision tree can be seen as the partition of the data now the partition is done by hyperplane parallel to the coordinates. When the data is represented in $R^2$ it is partitioned by lines parallel to $x$ or $y$ axis. So we can say that at each node it's a binary split.

In the following paper, I saw the definition of
https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.05141
decision space which is a generalisation of the definition of the decision tree. The definition of decision space is given in section 4 of the paper. Roughly the definition says that we can create partition with the minimum and maximum value of each column and that will create a box(polyhedra) and each box is like the leaf in a decision tree.
Following example make it more clear
[image]

Hence we can see that given a decision tree we create a decision space. Now the opposite is not true. Given a decision space, we cannot create a decision tree. A counter-example is given by the following rule set.

[image]

My question is what condition should we impose on decision space to make it a decision tree? In a paragraph in the paper, it was given as follows

> A decision tree cannot generate all axis-parallel rectangles. Indeed,
> a decision tree belongs to the data mining family of
> divide-and-conquer algorithms that imposes constraints on the search.
> Intuitively, a cut in the space along the border of an element, either
> vertical or horizontal, should not cut any element.

This statement is not clear to me. Any explanation welcome.

Comment: It's not clear to me either. It seems they talk about some algorithm to generate decision trees and not about all possible decision trees, but for this they need to specify the algorithm. Do they give definition of decision tree?

Comment: No, they didn't define the decision tree. I thought it might be too common in the literature but never found a mathematical one.